# JPA Column definition not working with COMMENT for H2 database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, h2, columndefinition

This syntax is working for Mysql while it is not for H2. SQL Syntax for h2 comment seems to be different from Mysql.

Any suggestion on how generalize this situation? I need support for both database.
Even a way to avoid Comment when using H2 could be good for me.

```
@Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(80) COMMENT 'User email'")
private String email;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: H2 by itself accepts `CREATE TABLE TEST(C VARCHAR(80) COMMENT 'User email');`, but this syntax isn't documented.